# Fold effect on brush Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, brush

I am here with what I think to be a basic question but I really can't find where is the option. I am recreating a diagram but I am not getting how to recreate this fold effect on the arrow:
[image]

If is unclear, here is a quick example of how my arrows appear:
[image]

Thank you guys!

Final result using strokes:

[image]

Billy Kerr's answer was the most complete so I'll mark that as helpful, but you all guys would deserve that. Thank you Joel and user!

Answer (score 2):

It's two filled shapes. To recreate them, you could trace them with the Pen Tool. Then fill using the eyedropper to sample the colours from the raster image. For a more realistic look, you might want to fill them with gradients.

[image]

It's also possible to create both shapes by applying a calligraphic brush to a simple curves.

[image]

You could even create one curve, apply the calligraphic brush, then split the shapes at the middle curve anchor, then colour each differently, which is what I did in the above example.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Gradient stroke with caligraphic brush]

[image: Caligraphic brush options]

1 Draw your path

2 Apply a gradient on the stroke

3 Apply a Caligraphic brush

4 Adjust the stroke value so it's thick enough

5 Open the brush options and adjust the angle

6 Outline the stroke (Menu > Object > Path > outline stroke)

7 Draw in the Arrowhead manually

Sorry I can't post all the screen shots I had. I'm only allowed a couple of image links

Comment: Nifty little trick there, Joel! Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

No folding is necessary. It can as well be 2 different shapes. They are very easy to draw with the pen tool. I gave to them magenta strokes to make them well wisible. The fills are slightly different gradients.

[image]

For a beginner the pen tool can look out a disobedient messmaker. But it responds loyally once you catch the idea and keep the anchor point count in the minimum. The direct selection tool is for fine-tuning the curves